# Delet an Entity from a Collection in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have a Vendor that might possibly have up to 2 or many contact attached to it in the database and I want to implement a delete command from my controller...

When a user hit on the delete button in the front-end I want to check in the database if the vendor has up to 2 or more contact before the action is allowed else revoke it. Because a vendor cannot have a 0 contact it must have @ least 1 contact remaining in the database

when i retrieve all the contact by vendorID from database if i try this

```
if(contact > 2)
  {
      //do delete the choose contact
  }
  else
      // Revoke
```

it not working my contact service returns IEnumerable of contact from my service

Please how can I go around it to work, kind of lose the logic behind it.

thanks for your time

```
public IEnumerable<VendorContact> GetAllVendorContacts(int vendorId)
    {
        var contacts = _unitOfWork.VendorContactRepository.Get(v => v.VendorId == vendorId, null, "");

        return contacts;
    }
```

this is my service that get all Contact by Vendor

Comment: MVC doens't deal with SQL Servers, so it appears you're confused on the frameworks you're using.  More often than not, questions about data within MVC are regarding using Entity Framework.

Comment: Yes am Using Code First, Entity Framwork

Comment: You want to delete the contacts themselves or delete the relationship between the two?

Comment: *What* is not working? The first code block doesn't contain anything that *could* work.